# Calling a function from html and getting results from angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am stuck on getting value back after I call a function in my HTML file.  I did some research and tried could things but no success.  Please see below code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-9"><label for="IPAddr">IP Address</label><input  ng-model="IPAddr" id="IPAddr" name="IPAddr" ng-blur="IPAvail=validateIP()"           
     type="text" class="form-control">{{IPAvail}}</div>          
  </div>
```

A basic form with an input field for IP address. Calls the validateIP(), and shows returned value "{{IPAvail}}".

**JS:**

```
$scope.validateIP = function(IPAvail) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var ipVar = $.param({ip: $scope.ipadd});
    $http({
        url: 'https://test.com/flask_server/findIP',
        method: "POST",
        data: ipVar
    })
    .then(function(response) {     
        $scope.result = response.data;
        ip = response.data;     

         if (ip.indexOf("10.10.10.1") >=0) {
            alert("Matches with IP")
            IPAvail = "Yes"
            return IPAvail
        } else {
            alert("Does not match with IP")
        }
        IPAvail = "No"
        return IPAvail
});
};
```

I simplified the code to make it easy to read but basically, everything is working correctly but the only thing I am having an issue is returning IPAvail variable back to HTML so it can be used here:

```
type="text" class="form-control">{{IPAvail}}</div>
```

Thanks
Damon

Comment: Instead of returning `IPAvail`, set `$scope.IPAvail` to the required value. Rather than use `onblur`, you should defer to `ng-change="validateIP()"`

Comment: That did the trick .. thanks!!!!  i see it works with ng-blur as well, just for info can you please explain why I should use ng-change instead of blur?

Comment: I explained in the answer. Please let me know if you need further clarification. Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning `IPAvail`, set `$scope.IPAvail` to the required value. Rather than use `onblur`, you should defer to `ng-change="validateIP()"`.

Using `ng-change` allows AngularJS to know about the effect. Otherwise you may run into trouble with AngularJS *not* knowing. It is better for AngularJS to know.